# How to linearize a min equality?

Tags: linear-transformations, linear-programming

I have a linear program that has a constraint as follows :

$$a = \min\{b,x\},$$

where $x$ is the variable.

I tried to write it as $$a\leq\min\{b,x\}\tag{1},$$

and

$$a\geq\min\{b,x\}.\tag{2}$$

Equation $(1)$ is equivalent to the two inequalities :

$$a\leq b,$$ and $$a\leq x.$$

How to deal with equation $(2)$?

Comment: [How to linearize max, min, and abs functions](https://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-linearize-max-min-and-abs-functions/), posted by Prof. Leandro C. Coelho, Ph.D., the Canada Research Chair in Integrated Logistics, provides a method for the general min function. Erwin Kalvelagen stated in a comment to an answer I've deleted that it should be non-convex, that usually a general OR condition ($x \ge a$ or $x \ge b$) is modeled with binary variables, and he suspects penalyzing the $S^+, S^−$ (mentioned in the method) will change the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are both constants, then there are two cases. If $a<b$, then the constraint can be written as $x=a$. If $a=b$, then the constraint can be written as $x\geq b$. If $a>b$, then the constraint is violated.

---

If $a$ is a variable, there are also two cases.

1. The first is that $a$ has a negative coefficient in the linear minimization objective (or a positive coefficient in the maximization objective). If that's the case, then it will actually just suffice to put what you've put: $a\leq b$, and $a\leq x$. The reason is that decreasing $a$ below the minimum (violating inequality) would incur a detrimental cost in the objective.
2. The second is that $a$ has non-negative coefficient in the minimization objective. If that's the case, then the constraint cannot necessarily be enforced, since the problem may not be convex. For instance, the simple problem
   $$\begin{align*}
   \min_{x,a}\quad& a\\
   \text{s.t.}\quad& a=\min\{1,x\}\\
   &x,a\geq 0
   \end{align*}$$
   is non-convex since $(x,a)=(0,0)$ is feasible, and $(x,a)=(2,1)$ is feasible, but a convex combination of these $(x,a)=(1,\frac{1}{2})$ is not feasible. Linear programmes must have convex feasible regions.

---

If $a$ is a constant and $b$ is a variable, then again, the problem mightn't be convex, so once again you can't necessarily write a linear constraint which is equivalent. For example, 
$$\begin{align*}
\min_{x,b}\quad& x+b\\
\text{s.t.}\quad& 1=\min\{b,x\}
\end{align*}$$
is not convex, since $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$ are both feasible but the convex combination $(2,2)$ is not.

---

In all cases, you can turn your linear programme into a mixed-integer linear programme by defining a new variable $z\in\{0,1\}$ which equals $1$ when $a=b$ and equals $0$ when $a=x$.
In particular, you can write the constraints as
$$\begin{align*}
a&\leq b\\
a&\leq x\\
a&\geq x-Mz\\
a&\geq b-M(1-z)\\
x&\leq b+Mz\\
b&\leq x+Mb\\
z&\in\{0,1\}
\end{align*}
$$
where $M$ is a [big-M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method) value.

---